# Laravel error when creating new project: proceed without cache

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm just starting with laravel. I'm following this laravel guide. My environment is an aws server running php 5.6, I have already installed composer.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart#deleting-tasks

When I type:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel quickstart --prefer-dist
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot create cache directory /home/ubuntu/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
```

How can I fix this? Is this a major problem? If I proceed would I run into trouble after?

Also, is it bad practice to use sudo?

Comment: `sudo chmod -R o+w /home/ubuntu/.composer/`

Comment: Sudo should be used only when necessary. I'm guessing your use of sudo created something in the `.composer` directory owned by the root user. Do `sudo rm -rf /home/ubuntu/.composer/cache` to clear out the cache, and only run `composer` commands as the `ubuntu` user in the future. Without the cache, composer will be *very* slow installing.

Comment: Yeah, but it could resolve this fast. It is not SAFE way. The other way is create a new project MVC project at non-private folder. Ex. `cd /var/www/html` and `composer create-project laravel/laravel quickstart --prefer-dist` without using sudo like ceejayoz said

Comment: I tried sudo rm -rf /home/ubuntu/.composer/cache.  I still get the same error. Not sure how to fix this. I am really new to both laravel and aws maybe I stuffed up the permissions of the folders or something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you installed composer pretty sure you used $ sudo command because of that the `~/.composer` folder was created by the root.

Run this to fix the issue:

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.composer
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this method which I used for my project on a LAMP server

```
sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel quickstart --prefer-dist
```

After that, you change the permission back to www-data user & group

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data quickstart\ -R
sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu_user_name
```